# Не запускается QtDesigner!

Tags: python

У меня стоит python 3.9. Через консоль я установил PyQT5 и pyqt5-tools. Перешел в корень python чтобы запустить дизайнер, а он выдает такую ошибку - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал манипуляции с папкой platforms, закидыванием ее в корень Python и прочие методы, однако ничего не помогает. Как сделать чтобы дизайнер работал?